# I can't get the domain mapping working for a Wordpress blog deployment on the Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, dns

I've followed this tutorial [here](https://onepagezen.com/domain-name-configuration-wordpress-google-cloud/#wordpress-click-to-deploy-instructions). There are two options mentioned in the tutorial 1. WordPress Bitnami instructions and 2. WordPress Click-to-deploy instructions.  I used the second option because that appears easiest to do. I followed other tutorials to do domain mapping management and it works for my main website but for some reason not for the blog. It actually looks like the administration steps taken below led Google to do some mapping automatically:

[image]

In these instructions of [the tutorial I followedr](https://onepagezen.com/domain-name-configuration-wordpress-google-cloud/#wordpress-click-to-deploy-instructions), you go to the wp-admin page and that works fine and Wordpress is installed perfectly well and humming along. Then it says to simply add your domain address with www. and .com in a form (Settings > General)  (in my case, www.blog.collectiwise.com).  I did that and a message appeared that the new setting was now saved, in green, so I assumed now I can go to my website and see the WP blog stem, but unfortunately I'm redirected to a Virgin Media page that says it can't find "www.blog.collectiwise.com".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a subdomain zone, as per [whois](https://whois.domaintools.com/collectiwise.com) your domain "collectiwise.com" is using:

```
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com
```

Since this is different from your whois info, I assume you are managing collectiwise.com and blog.collectiwise.com separately, so there are 2 options:

1. Create `blog.collectiwise.com` and `www.collectiwise.com` in the same zone you already have for `collectiwise.com`.

or

2. If you want to handle DNS zones separately then you must add the following NS registries to your main TLD domain `collectiwise.com` for `blog.collectiwise.com`:

   ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com

That way clients requesting any DNS information such as `blog.collectiwise.com` will be redirected by your TLD domain into your GCP public DNS subdomain zone.